# SQLAlchemy in flask automap_base not mapping classes?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

long time listener first time caller. I'm making a flask app to create a small API off a SQLite db. Like the simplest thing in the world. I can query the db schema fine, so I know the engine is working. But as soon as I declare a class object with what is absolutely a class name, I get a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'WarID'`. The error is so generic I haven't been able find anything. Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi.

#### Here's the app.py

```
import numpy as np

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func

from flask import Flask, jsonify


#################################################
# Database Setup
#################################################
try:
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///static/data/iWars.sqlite")

    # reflect an existing database into a new model
    Base = automap_base()
    # reflect the tables
    Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)
    print("All about that base")
    print(Base)
    # # Save reference to the table
    # tribes = Base.classes.Tribes
    warsTable = Base.classes.Wars
    print("yes no maybe")
except Exception as e:
    print("Hey what's up looks like something gnarly happened")
    print(e)

#################################################
# Flask Setup
#################################################
app = Flask(__name__)


#################################################
# Flask Routes
#################################################

@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    """List all available api routes."""
    return (
        f"Available Routes:<br/>"
        # f"/api/v1.0/tribes<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/listwars<br/>"
    )

@app.route("/api/v1.0/listwars")
def warsRoute():
    # Create our session (link) from Python to the DB
    session = Session(engine)

    # Query all
    results = session.query(warsTable.WarID).all()

    session.close()

    # Create a dictionary from the row data and append to a list of all_passengers
    all_passengers = []
    for id in results:
        wars_dict = {}
        wars_dict["id"] = id
        all_passengers.append(wars_dict)

    return jsonify(all_passengers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### Here's the run

Notice that as soon as it hits the object declaration, it drops into the except block with just `Wars` as the exception, and then when I open the route I get the error shown.

```
(mlenv) ianmacsmacbook:USIndigenousWars ianmacmoore$ python app.py
All about that base
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Base'>
Hey what's up looks like something gnarly happened
Wars
 Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with watchdog (fsevents)
All about that base
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Base'>
Hey what's up looks like something gnarly happened
Wars
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 955-667-953
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/ianmacmoore/Documents/BluePlusRed/USIndigenousWars/app.py", line 56, in warsRoute
    results = session.query(warsTable.WarID).all()
NameError: name 'warsTable' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:19:54] "GET /api/v1.0/listwars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:40:37] "GET /api/v1.0/wars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:40:37] "GET /api/v1.0/wars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:40:37] "GET /api/v1.0/wars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2023 13:40:37] "GET /api/v1.0/wars?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

#### Here're the class definitions used to initially write to the db

```
class Against(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Against'
    TribeID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    AgainstCode = Column(Integer)
    WarID = Column(Integer)

class Tribes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tribes'
    TribeID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    TribeName = Column(String(255))
    TribeName2 = Column(String(255))
    TribeName3 = Column(String(255))

class Wars(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Wars'
    WarID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    WarName = Column(String(255))
    StartYear = Column(Integer)
    EndYear = Column(Integer)
    WikiLink = Column(String(255))
    LengthYears = Column(Integer)

class YearSum(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'YearSum'
    Year = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    SumWars = Column(Integer)
    y = Column(Integer)
```

#### And here's the table object being created from a Jupyter Notebook on the same db

```
wars = Table("Wars", metadata_obj, autoload_with=engine)
wars
```

```
Table('Wars', MetaData(bind=None), Column('index', BIGINT(), table=<Wars>), Column('WarID', BIGINT(), table=<Wars>), Column('War Name', TEXT(), table=<Wars>), Column('StartYear', BIGINT(), table=<Wars>), Column('EndYear', BIGINT(), table=<Wars>), Column('WikiLink', TEXT(), table=<Wars>), Column('LengthYears', BIGINT(), table=<Wars>), schema=None)
```

#### Here's what I'm running

```
conda list '^(python|flask|sqlal)'
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python                    3.7.13               hdfd78df_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2           py37hecd8cb5_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1  
python-lsp-black          1.2.1            py37hecd8cb5_0  
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-lsp-server         1.5.0            py37hecd8cb5_0  
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-snappy             0.6.0            py37h23ab428_3  
python.app                3                py37hca72f7f_0  
sqlalchemy                1.4.39           py37hca72f7f_0
```

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `wars` the automapped class and `wars` the route function are both declared in the module's top-level namespace, so the declaration of the route function overwrites the automapped class.

The error message

> 'function' object has no attribute 'WarID'

refers to the route function, *not* the automapped class.

Choose a different name for one of them, that does not conflict with any other names in the namespace.

Comment: I changed table object name, route url, and route function names. It's more readable for sure, however the error is still with the object instantiation.

`NameError: name 'warsTable' is not defined

Comment: I don't see `warsTable` in the code in the question, so I can't give you the solution. But `NameError` has a single cause: you reference a name that is not defined in your code. So you may have something like `foo = warsTable.bar` and you will get an `NameError` if `warsTable` has not been defined earlier in your code.

Comment: Thanks for looking again. Sorry for the confusion. I updated the code in the post with the changes I made based on your first comment. `warsTable` ought to be a table object declared with `Base.classes.Wars` right? I literally copied the sqlalchemy documentation example for `automap_base()`. I have the original class definitions also above. I've tested that the engine is working by querying the table names, and `Wars` is there.